# Laravel 9 adding foreign key constraint returns 150 error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, laravel-9

I have created `Roles` table with `Users` table, I am trying to add `foreign key` to `users` table, but when I migrate, it returns `150 error`.
[image]
I have googled a lot, I got a lot of answers, but no answer worked for me.
**create_users_table Migration:**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->foreignId('role_id')
            ->constrained()
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**create_roles_table Migration:**

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? I am stuck..

Comment: where is the migration about "restaurant_menu" table?

Comment: @GiacomoM `restaurant_menu` is database name, not table.

Comment: you first create "roles" table and after "user" table, right?

Comment: @GiacomoM users table were already created with `laravel/ui`, i create `roles` table now, and trying to improve users table with foreign key.

Comment: you have to check 2 things: the migration of roles executes before migration of users. You have some records in `users` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `roles` table doesn't exist when you're creating a foreign key inside the `users` table.

So, your `roles` migration must be executed before you create a foreign key inside the `users` table.

There are 2 ways you can do this.

1- You either rename the roles and change the timestamp in name to be before the users migration. ( Not a good way though )

2- First create the tables and then create a new migration to insert the foreign key inside the users table.

Comment: First one is a good way i guess, thanks